# how to query column in SQL database via UPPER case conversion IN NODE.js javascript code..

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Hi I've recently updated my SEQUELIZE node package from v3 to v4.

In my code I used to query my user table via the following sytnax

```
       var option = {
        where: ["upper(email) = ?", ssousername.toUpperCase()]
    };
```

This would effectively query my user table converting all user emails in DB to uppercase.

When upgrading to V4 I am now given the following error thrown by the above query

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed.
```

I cannot find any documentation as to how I should syntactically format my former query executed via a node.js backend in order to produce the following SQL query

```
SELECT UPPER(email) AS email
FROM dashboard."user" WHERE email='user@email.com';
```

Would love some help , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are working on deprecating all string operators I think. Under [querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#basics) it seems to suggest doing it like this:

```
let option = {
  where: sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('upper', sequelize.col('email')),
    ssousername.toUpperCase()
  ),
};
```